# How to get the caller url in struts2?

Tags: tags, struts2

I have a struts2 page which uses a shared action using `<s:action>` with `executeResult="true"` to add header contents to the page. However, there's some processing need to be done in the *header* action, which needs to retrieve the url of the actual page(aka the caller page). But if I use `<s:url>` within the header action's jsp, it only retrieve the url of the header action. So I would like to ask the experts here to enlighten me on how to achieve the result I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not convinced this is a robust thing to want to do-why do you want to access the "calling" page?

Comment: I wanted to set up a locale changing form in the header and that's why.

Comment: Why do you need to know the calling page for that?

Comment: The `calling page` I meant is the main page that embeds the header action. So the browser will return to the current page every time the locale changes.

Comment: Oh, I'd do that in an interceptor or something. I get nervous any time the view layer thinks it needs to know explicitly where it got called from, that's all.

Comment: Since each request is independent so I think it's a must to save the current page url on the page in order to `reload` the page with a different locale. You are welcomed to provide a interceptor-wise solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So below is what I did to do it.

On the main page, use `s:url` and `s:set` to obtain the current url as well as parameters and save it in request scope

```
<s:set name="pageurl" scope="request">
    <s:url includeParams="none" encode="true"/>
</s:set>
<s:set name="pageparams" scope="request" value="#parameters"/>
```

On the header page, you can retrieve them using below

```
        <form action="<s:property value='#attr.pageurl'/>" >
            <s:iterator value="#attr.pageparams" var="param">
                <s:hidden name="%{#param.key}" value="%{#param.value}" id="_header_%{#param.key}"/>                 
            </s:iterator>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow... so feel free to correct me if I'm not at all answering what you want.

But you should be able to use the `<s:set>` tag with the appropriate scope (probably request) before you call `<s:action>` to make the values you need available to the next action. See: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/set.html

Comment: What I want is like, there's an action `header.action` in another  action `page1.action`, and within `header.do` I want to retrieve the url of `page1.action` or whatever page calls `header.action`

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the request object for this:

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer"); //referer spelling intentional
```

Do whatever you need with it via string manipulation.